# How to filter out intraweek data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, filter

I have a query that I'm leveraging for a dashboard visualization. The only issue with the query is that it includes data for the current week - which is problematic because the week is not fully baked. Ideally, I would like to add a filter that pulls in data w/in the last 52 weeks but excludes data with a date that is greater than the most recent reporting week (Sun - Sat).
Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT (DATE_TRUNC('week',cj.created_at:: timestamptz) + '5 days':: 
         interval)::date
       ,CASE WHEN o.vertical IS NULL OR o.vertical NOT IN 
        ('Auto','Franchise') THEN 'SMB'
       ELSE o.vertical END as vertical
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT cj.native_candidate_job_id) as applicant_traffic
FROM dim_candidate_jobs cj
JOIN dim_organizations o ON cj.native_organization_id = 
     o.native_organization_id
WHERE o.demo = false
    AND NOT(o.name ~~* any (array['%test%','%api%']))
    AND cj.created_at:: date > current_date - interval '52 weeks'
    AND cj.created_at:: date < (DATE_TRUNC('week',current_date:: 
         timestamptz) + '1 day':: interval)::date
    AND o.current = 'Y'
    AND cj.current = 'Y'
GROUP BY 1,2;;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
and cj.created_at >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '52 weeks'
and cj.created_at < date_trunc('week', current_date)
```